# PostScript - from file to file

Tags: file, line, postscript

Cheers,

I'm trying to read char by char from a file using PostScript and then writing them to another.

I can push all the chars to the stack doing:

```
(inputFile)(r)file 1 string readstring
```

But now I can't write the chars to the other file. I tried

```
(outputFile)(w)file = writestring
```

and other methods, but none seems to work.

EDIT: code

```
/infile (text.txt) (r) file def % open files and save file objects
/outfile (output.txt) (w) file def
/buff 1 string def % your buffer for reading operations
{ % loop
    infile buff readstring
    { %ifelse
         outfile (>) writestring
         outfile exch writestring
         outfile (<) writestring
         outfile (\n) writestring

    }
    { %else

            exit % exit the loop
    } ifelse
} bind loop
```

Every char gets > and < , but they still on the same line

EDIT: found the problem : The output file CAN NOT have .txt entension

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding the way PostScript works. It is a stack based language, so operators consume their operands from the stack, and push their result (if any) onto the stack. So to annotate your examples:

```
(inputFile)           % push a string with the filename onto the stack
(r)                   % push a string with the access mode onto the stack
file                  % the file operator consumes two string operands, opens
                      % a file and returns the file object on the stack
1 string              % create an empty string of maximum length 1
readstring            % readstring consumes a string object and a file object from
                      % the stack, it reads bytes from the file object until the string
                      % is full or reaches EOF. It then returns the substring filled,  
                      % and a boolean indicating the outcome.


(outputFile)          % push a string with the filename onto the stack
(w)                   % push a string with the access mode onto the stack
file                  % the file operator consumes two string operands, opens
                      % a file and returns the file object on the stack
=                     % consumes the top object on the stack, and writes a textual
                      % representation of the object to stdout (usually -file-)
writestring           % consumes two operands from the stack, a file object and a
                      % string to write. OOPS! no objects on the stack, so we generate
                      % a stackunderflow
```

Now, if I assume that you meant these two lines of code to be sequential then I can see that we will have a string on the stack when we get to writestring, but there are two problems. Firstly the '=' has consumed the file operand so that its not present. Secondly, if you remove the '=' then what you have on the stack before you call write string is '(string) -file-' whereas the order of the operands needs to be '-file- (string)'. A simple 'exch' will resolve that problem.

So your code ought to be:

```
(inputFile) (r) file 1 string readstring
(outputFile) (w) file exch writestring
```

I'd suggest that, when asking for help, you state the errors you are getting, as this is likely to help people understand more complex problems.

Comment: That made it. However I can't add a newline. I did (outputFile)(w)file (\n) writestring and it's simply ignored. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: That should have worked I would have thought, are you sure its ignored ? You checked with a binary editor ? Oh and you do realise that opening a file for write doesn't move the underlying file pointer ? If you want to add to the file you have to keep it open, not keep reopening it.

Comment: Look at the post and see the code I have so far. Can you give a hint if anything's wrong?

Comment: I figured out what's happening. If type those commands in GhostScript everything goes well, but when I import the file ( (file.ps)run ) the newline is ignored, but don't know why..